# Controller Scope Array not load updated data on another controller

Tags: angularjs

i created one index page which have "NavigationController" and bind the menu on index page. when i redirect to new page controller and inject it "NavigationController" to bind latest menu on next page but it always display old menu. when i refresh the page then it loads nice with new menu.

```
<nav class="static-sidebar" role="navigation">
                <ul ng-controller="NavigationController" id="sidebar" ng-init="!layoutLoading">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-include="'templates/nav_renderer.html'" ng-show="{{item.hasRights}}" ng-cloak></li>
                </ul>
```

And Controller with my factory method which return meun is :

```
$scope.menu = GetHttpRequest.GetMenu();
```

Now, I Add into Another page i.e

```
<div ng-controller="NavigationController"></div>
```

but this not load latest menu untill i refresh the page

so , can you help me in this?

Comment: Please Create a plunker that reproduced the same issue.

Comment: can u provide plunker

Answer (score 1):

`{{}}` not needed in `ng-show`.

Use `ng-show="item.hasRights"` instead of `ng-show="{{item.hasRights}}"`

Comment: I could show only this error from your abov code. Create plunker/fiddle to find the exact one

Answer (score 0):

If it works after refreshing it means that it is something with loading order in your site. Check if you have correct order of loading, like: vendor lbirariers -> your libraries -> (...) -> your controller

also check your dependency injection headers in js files, cause you might skipped something